# Question regarding the expression ¨One kind of + [plural noun].¨

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, prepositions, grammatical-number, agreement

Which one is correct?

- There is only one kind of sunglasses, and it´s small.
- There is only one kind of sunglasses, and they are small.

Comment: "Which one is correct?" is proofreading, and the answer depends on what your sentence actually means. Please [edit] your question to include that (particularly, **what** is small?)

Comment: Either way sounds jarring, which is on the way to Orwell's 'unacceptable', whatever more mechanical 'rule' might be dredged up from arcane works on grammar. 'There is only one kind of sunglasses: small [ones]' sound more natural (and colons seem to license most completives).

Comment: The fact that ***one kind*** is "singular" is irrelevant. We use the plural verb form for *My glasses **are** misted up, My trousers **are** dirty* even though the relevant subject nouns refer to single entities. Hence *This* (rarely, *these*) *kind of sunglasses **are** easily damaged.*

Comment: @FF 'While only one type of glasses are shown in this tutorial ...'??

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Not as big a usage difference as I'd have expected, but [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this+kind+of+glasses%2Cthese+kind+of+glasses&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) shows we favour ***this** kind of glasses* over ***these...***

Comment: ...and [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kind+of+glasses+is%2Ckind+of+glasses+are&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) clearly shows the preference for *kind of glasses **are*** over *kind of glasses **is.***

Comment: ...and [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=There+are+only+one+kind%2CThere+is+only+one+kind&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) clearly shows we massively prefer *There **is** only one kind of [glasses, wine worth drinking, whatever]* over *There **are** only one kind*.

Comment: I've only found examples of 'type of pliers is' (admittedly only two: 'another type of pliers is' and 'a special type of pliers is'), but it would be my choice.

Comment: I can't explain why [*type of glasses **is / are***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=type+of+glasses+is%2Ctype+of+glasses+are&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) are now equally common (a century ago it was almost always singular), whereas it's still practically always singular with [*type of scissors*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=type+of+scissors+is%2Ctype+of+scissors+are&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20)